# Exclusions in SumIf Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an income spreadsheet. It tracks biweekly income. The top row reflects the dates of the checks. There are 26 biweekly checks in most years. Some of my deductions only occur 2 times a month. I am attempting to make calculations that exclude the 3rd check. I've tried SumIf and CountIf formulas but can't get them to work.

I've tried different variations of this:

```
=SUMIF(B1:AA1,MONTH(B1)=MONTH(C1),B61:AA61)
```

I added ADDRESS() inside MONTH() of that function. It seems MONTH() doesn't like the date string and I realize that the above function is only testing the 2 cells and not the array. All the spreadsheets I've made are relatively simple compared to what I've reviewed on here.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Easiest way with SUMIF (in my view) is an intermediate column (hidden) with codes controlling how to sum. This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, the only dates where a third paycheck occurs in a particular month is on the 29th, 30th, or 31st.

The `DAY()` function extracts the day number from a date

Incorporating this into the given formula:

`=SUMIF(B1:AA1,DAY(B1:AA1)<29,B61:AA61)`

You might be able to anchor your cell references so that this formula is fillable.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant method, but I solved my issues with this:

```
=COUNT(filter(B1:1,NE(ARRAYFORMULA(B1:1),ARRAYFORMULA(D1:1)),B1:1<now()))
```

I was also trying to get a running balance on a loan I am paying off. Hence the NOW() in the filter.

Extracting the date would have excluded a viable paycheck.